# Increasing cpu and ram usage while calling update for multiple QSGNodes

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, opengl

I create an application with Qt Scene Graph (Qt 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04). It has about 12 instances of QSGNodes and calls update for them every 30ms.

I don't have any problem with updating one of them, but when i call update for all of them, cpu and ram usage began to increase. After some hours cpu usage will be near 100%. (under normal conditions cpu usage should be around 3-4).

Here is minimal version(Sorry for long code, It's simplest version that produces this bug):

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MainWindow w;
   w.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "gui/diagramgraph.h"
namespace Ui {
   class MainWindow;
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
     Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QTimer>
#include "gui/diagramgraph.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
     QMainWindow(parent),
     ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
     ui->setupUi(this);
     qmlRegisterType<DiagramGraph>("DiagramGraph", 1, 0, "DiagramGraph");
     QTimer *updateTimer = new QTimer(this);
     for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
         QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
         view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/ui/diagram.qml"));
         view->setClearBeforeRendering(true);
         QObject *object = view->rootObject();
         DiagramGraph* graph = object->findChild<DiagramGraph *>("diagram");
         QObject::connect(updateTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), graph, SLOT(update()));
         QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view, this);
         ui->vetical->addWidget(container);
    }
updateTimer->setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer);
updateTimer->start(30);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
     delete ui;
}
```

gui/diagramgraph.h

```
#ifndef DIAGRAMGRAPH_H
#define DIAGRAMGRAPH_H
#include <QQuickItem>
class DiagramGraph : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
       DiagramGraph();
       void init();
    protected:
       QSGNode *updatePaintNode(QSGNode *, UpdatePaintNodeData *);
       void geometryChanged(const QRectF &newGeometry, const QRectF &oldGeometry);
 };
 #endif // DIAGRAMGRAPH_H
```

gui/diagramgraph.cpp

```
#include "samples.h"
#include "diagramgraph.h"
class DiagramGraphNode : public QSGNode
{
public:
    Samples * samples;
};
DiagramGraph::DiagramGraph()
{
     setFlag(ItemHasContents, true);
}
QSGNode * DiagramGraph::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData *){
    DiagramGraphNode *n= static_cast<DiagramGraphNode *>(oldNode);
    QRectF rect = boundingRect();
    if (rect.isEmpty()) {
        delete n;
        return 0;
    }
    if (!n) {
        n = new DiagramGraphNode();
        n->samples = new Samples();
        n->appendChildNode(n->samples);
    }
    n->samples->updateGeometry();
    return n;
}
void DiagramGraph::geometryChanged(const QRectF &newGeometry, const QRectF &oldGeometry){
    update();
    QQuickItem::geometryChanged(newGeometry, oldGeometry);
 }
```

gui/samples.h

```
#ifndef SAMPLES_H
#define SAMPLES_H
#include <QSGGeometryNode>
class Samples : public QSGGeometryNode
{
public:
    Samples();
    void updateGeometry();
private:
    QSGGeometry _geometry;
};
#endif // SAMPLES_H
```

gui/samples.cpp

```
#include "samples.h"
#include <QtGui/QColor>
#include <QtQuick/QSGSimpleMaterial>
struct LineMaterial
{
    QColor color;
};
class LineShader : public QSGSimpleMaterialShader<LineMaterial>
{
    QSG_DECLARE_SIMPLE_SHADER(LineShader, LineMaterial)

 public:
    LineShader() {
         setShaderSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, ":/shaders/shaders/samples.vsh");
         setShaderSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, ":/shaders/shaders/samples.fsh");
    }
    QList<QByteArray> attributes() const {  return QList<QByteArray>() << "y" << "t"; }
    void updateState(const LineMaterial *m, const LineMaterial *) {
         program()->setUniformValue(id_color, m->color);
    }
    void resolveUniforms() {
        id_color = program()->uniformLocation("color");
    }
    private:
        int id_color;
};
struct Vertex {
    float y;
    float t;
    inline void set(float yy, float tt) { y = yy; t = tt; }
};
static const QSGGeometry::AttributeSet &attributes()
{
    static QSGGeometry::Attribute attr[] = {
         QSGGeometry::Attribute::create(0, 1, GL_FLOAT, true),
         QSGGeometry::Attribute::create(1, 1, GL_FLOAT),
    };
    static QSGGeometry::AttributeSet set = { 2, 2 * sizeof(float), attr };
    return set;
 }
 Samples::Samples()
    : _geometry(attributes(), 0){
    setGeometry(&_geometry);
    _geometry.setLineWidth(3);
    _geometry.setDrawingMode(GL_LINES);
    QSGSimpleMaterial<LineMaterial> *m = LineShader::createMaterial();
    m->state()->color = QColor("red");
    m->setFlag(QSGMaterial::Blending);
    setMaterial(m);
    setFlag(OwnsMaterial);
}
void Samples::updateGeometry()
{
    _geometry.allocate(20);
    Vertex *v = (Vertex *) _geometry.vertexData();
    for (uint i=0; i < 20; i++){
        v[i].set(.5, i);
    }
 }
```

mainwindow.ui

```
 just a QVBoxLayout
```

diagram.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import DiagramGraph 1.0
Item{
    id: diagram_main
    DiagramGraph{
        id: diagram_graph
        objectName: "diagram"
        anchors.left: diagram_main.left
        height: 100
    }
}
```

shaders/samples.fsh

```
uniform lowp vec4 color;
uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = color * qt_Opacity;
}
```

shaders/samples.vsh

```
attribute highp float y;
attribute highp float t;
uniform highp mat4 qt_Matrix;
void main(void)
{
     gl_Position =  qt_Matrix * vec4(t, y * 100.f, 0.f, 1.f);
}
```

Comment: Timer signals are probably placed into a queue. If the frame rate dips below 35fps - there are two update requests waiting in the queue. So, if the render can't keep up - the queue will grow. To test if it's the case, stop sending update events when it's at high CPU and then enable them again. If it drops to the levels at the application start, then the cause is confirmed.

Comment: @Velkan Creating instances of QQuickView (QML) in QMainWindow causes this problem. It resolved by creating instances in a QML file using a repeater. it seems that Qt has some problems with rendering multiple instances of a QQuickView in QMainWindow,